# Overclocking an AMD card

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, amd-radeon, overclocking

I want to overclock my graphics card so I can increase my FPS in Fallout 4, and I'm fairly new to this so I've come here for some assistance. I basically want to know how far I can safely push my graphics card for best performance. I'm using AMD OverDrive to overclock my card, and testing it with AfterBurner and Kombustor. My graphics card is the Radeon R7 260X, and I have a Novatech PowerStation 500W PSU. Here is a screenshot of how much I've pushed it so far:
[image]

I ran a test in Kombustor at 1920x1080 with 8xMSAA and I averaged about 45FPS with GPU temperatures of around 50°C. How much further can I safely push my GPU?

Comment: You can safely run your GPU at the specified stock speeds. Anything more, you are running beyond the specifications.

Comment: "I want to overclock my graphics card so I can increase my FPS in Fallout 4" - You do understand that the kind of overclocking you get on stock fans is going to increase your FPS by around 2-3 fps right?  You are not going to get big increases, if you can afford it, you are better of just getting a faster GPU.

Comment: @Ramhound I know barely anything about overclocking, that's why I'm here.

Comment: It really isn't hard.  You determine the maximum frequency where your system is stable.  You want that frequency to below the maximum temperature of the chip.  What the frequency will be will entirely depend on individual factors we can't know about. *All you do is keep trying until you determine what makes it unstable, then bring it down, until its stable.*

Comment: @imulsion If you barely know anything about a subject, you should learn more about it from broad sources of information, not ask specific questions.

Comment: The silicon is rated to roughly 80C at most for continuous operation. You are likely to experience side effects before you hit the temperature maximums.

Answer (score 0):

The [Radeon R7 260X](http://products.amd.com/en-us/search/Desktop-Graphics/AMD-Radeon%E2%84%A2-R7-Series/AMD-Radeon%E2%84%A2-R7-200-Series/AMD-Radeon%E2%84%A2-R7-260X/30) card is too slow and doing OC won't speed it up too much that you have any benefit. The chip of the R7 is simply not fast enough. Replace the low end card with a [R9 card](http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop/r9) to have more GPU power.